# Get columns from a query with jdbcTemplate BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, spring-jdbc, jdbctemplate

I have a problem and I need help.
The problem is that I am trying to get the result of a query using jdbctemplate and map that result in my File class.

MY CLASS FILE CONTAINS 3O PROPERTIES: 10 PROPERTIES OF TYPE LONG, STRING AND DATE.

```
@Table (name = "UZTFILE", schema = "UTIC")
public class File implements Serializable {
     private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING1")
     private String text1;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING2")
     private String text2;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING3")
     private String text3;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING4")
     private String text4;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING5")
     private String text5;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING6")
     private String text6;
       ......
     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_STRING10")
     private String text10;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_NUMBER1")
     private Long number1;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_NUMBER2")
     private Long number2;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_NUMBER3")
     private Long number3;

     @Column (name = "UZTFILE_NUMBER10")
     private Long number10;

--getters and setters and constructors ---
```

Query that I am executing:

```
List <File> files = new ArrayList <File> ();
// Query to execute
String query = "SELECT UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING1 AS INSTRUCCIONDECOBRO, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING2 AS COUNTERPART, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING3 AS CURRENCY VALUE AS UZF1.UZTFILE_NUMBER2, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING4 AS FORMADECOBRO, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING5 AS TIPOCUENTA, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING6 AS NROCUENTA, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING7 AS REFERENCE, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING8 AS TYPEIDENTIFICATION, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING9 AS NROIDENTIFICATION, UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING10 as NAMES FROM UZTFILE UZF1 ";

// Execution of the query
   files = jdbcTemplate.query (query, new BeanPropertyRowMapper <> (File.class));
```

When executing the query it does not give me an error, everything is correct but when showing the results the columns come out null and the error is due to the query that I am using uses aliases and the aliases do not match the name of the properties of the File class .

and Here comes my problem or query, since I cannot change the name of the properties of my class and neither can I remove the aliases from the query, since different querys are used and each querys use different aliases. for example:

```
String query1= "SELECT UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING1 AS INSTRUCCIONDECOBRO, UZF1.UZTFILE_NUMBER2 AS AGE, MORE FIELDS WITH ALIASES..... FROM UZTFILE WHERE "condicion"";
//Query 2
String query2= "SELECT UZF1.UZTFILE_STRING1 AS NOMBRES, UZF1.UZTFILE_NUMBER2 AS SIZE, MORE FIELDS WITH ALIASES........ FROM UZTFILE Where "condicion";
```

The problem is with the BeanPropertyRowMapper that does not identify the aliases and I cannot modify the properties of the classes or the queries, is there a solution or what do you recommend me to do?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to make your SQL uniform, i.e. use the same aliases where it is called from, and as you say, the `@Column` mapping in the class needs to match the columns returned in the query.

The other option is to use [`query(sql, rowMapper)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapper-), where your `rowMapper` will "manually" set what each column represents in the `File` class.